# Passing multiple parameters to Laravel API

Tags: laravel, rest

I need to filter my API using multiple parameters.
So how i can put my array of parameters to API Controller?

Comment: Can you supply more information what kind of data or which api endpoint?

Comment: For the community to better assist you, please provide code examples and describe where you're stuck and what you have tried.

Comment: It's a custom endpoint that takes data from db.

Answer (score 0):

If you add `Request $request` as a parameter in your controller functions, that will allow you to access any passed parameters through:

```
$request->input('parameter_1')
```

Sometimes you will need to protect your code in-case the parameter was not sent, in which case you can use:

```
isset($request->has('parameter_1'))
```

That will return false if this parameter was not sent with the request. Let me know if you meant something else.